# Need an application/app to measure page Loading time on Android , iPhone and iPad device

Tags: android, iphone, client-side, performance-testing

I need help in identification of any tool that can be installed on different devices (iPAD , iPhone, Android) and measures the page loading time/page rendering time for any app on that device. It is good if the tool generates different types of graph/charts for page loading/rendering time.

Comment: Not only that, but I'm pretty sure this would be impossible for iOS devices, as only a single app can be running at any time.

Comment: see that https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

Google Analytics [can measure this for you](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1205784). It's probably your best bet, especially for iOS devices. Look into `setSiteSpeedSampleRate()` to up the sampling rate from 1% of pageviews to 100% for your testing.